# Meaning of ハチ代(hachidai?)

Tags: translation, meaning

I’m reading the manga WORKING!! and came across the word in this strip (corner of the last panel):

[image: WORKING!! 104品め]

From the context and the -代 suffix it seems to refer to some kind of payment to the employees but I can’t figure out what ハチ refers to, and my searches online and in dictionaries were not successful. Did I misread it perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. It’s 八千代{やちよ}, name of another employee in the shop.